# Sending mail with php and html

Tags: php, html, email, post, iframe

I am using phpmailer to send normal pre-defined mails and it works fine.
Now what i want to do is, connect my texteditor with that php script so i can send really nice html mails.
Texteditor is template from CKEditor.
[image]

Everything that i write in textedtior is written with html tags like this
[image]

Then i have my php script from phpmailer to send mail. I have been thinking of maybe posting all html tags as post method and getting them in my php script. Maybe that is not the best idea, and even if it is i dont know how to post stuff out of input tags.

Any help would be much appreciated.

ps.
this is my php code

```
date_default_timezone_set('Etc/UTC');
require '../PHPMailerAutoload.php';
$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
$mail->Debugoutput = 'html';
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
$mail->Port = 587;
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = "??????@gmail.com";
$mail->Password = "?????";
$mail->setFrom('????@gmail.com', 'First Last');
$mail->addReplyTo('????@gmail.com', 'First Last');
$mail->addAddress('???@gmail.com', 'John Doe');
$mail->Subject = 'PHPMailer GMail SMTP test';
$mail->msgHTML(file_get_contents('contents.html'), dirname(__FILE__));
$mail->AltBody = 'This is a plain-text message body';
$mail->addAttachment('images/phpmailer_mini.png');
if (!$mail->send()) {
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo "Message sent!";
}
```

and about html code.. A lot of it is done by script that i got with the template

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>???</title>
    <script src="../ckeditor.js"></script>
    <script src="js/sample.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/samples.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="toolbarconfigurator/lib/codemirror/neo.css">
</head>
<body id="main">


<form class="newsletter-signup" form action="http://??????gmail.php" method="post">
<main>
        <div class="adjoined-top">
            <div class="grid-container">
                <div class="grid-width-100">
                    <div id="editor">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>  
</main>


<input type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-sand" value="subscribe">
</form>
<button onclick="loadPages()">Click Me</button>
<script>
    function loadPages(){
        //document.getElementsByClassName('lulul')[0].setAttribute('src', "http://??????/gmail.php");
        document.getElementsByClassName('lulul')[0].setAttribute('name',"content");
    }
</script>
<script>
    initSample();
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you show us your code, so we can help you properly, not based on supposition ?

Comment: Just know that HTML code doesn't automatically translate into pretty HTML emails. Very few email-clients support all HTML properly, and if you're adding CSS as well, you're gonna run into problems. Writing proper HTML-emails is a dark art - not really that simple (at least if you want it to work cross-client)

Comment: Set the `$mail->IsHTML(true);`

Comment: I posted additional code to my original question, as i cant post that much in comment.

Answer (score 0):

Basically the main idea of this is using full html body to see all html output correctly. Here is example

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
</head>
<body bgcolor="#ffffff" text="#000000">
        This is the body text<br>
<div class="moz-signature"><i><br>
<br>
The<br>
Frenks<br>
</i></div>
</body>
</html>
```

This will execute the html in the right way inside the mail body content :)

For example this will not work if you will pass just this!

```
<b>The Frenks</b>
```